# http headers without OPTION

Tags: http, http-headers

Normally if we want to check what are the http methods supported by the application, we send a OPTIONS request to the server, however if the application has disabled OPTIONS but has all the other methods enabled which include TRACE, HEAD, how do we determine the http methods supported by the application without OPTIONS method?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Or you just try them one-by-one.